# Does WCF + net.tcp support 3DES?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, 3des

I currently have an open WCF service running w/ netTcpBinding; however, I need to encrypt this channel. Does WCF support 3DES, or should I just handle the encryption/decryption on my authorized client/server?

Thanks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it does, via message security. Set the algorithmSuite attribue to the algorithm you wish to use. You can view the available algorithms here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.securityalgorithmsuite_members.aspx

There are a variety of TripleDES algorithms supported. I would hope that one of them would suffice. I believe the SecurityAlgorithmSuite class may be extended, so it might be possible to implement your own algorithm. However I am not sure how you would go about using it...I am not sure if the default configuration section supports third-party algorithms.